# Calling a plugin before document loads

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a very long table (more than 1000 rows) that takes a long time to load (up to 5 seconds). In turn, the rows have an anchor showing a dynamic tooltip using the qTip plugin.

Problem is that users need to wait for the document to load in order to see the tooltips. That is:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.anchor_in_row').qtip(...);
});
```

I am afraid that paging the table is not an option. Is there anyway I could begin showing the tooltips before the entire document is loaded? Thank you.

Comment: I have used qtip in the past to do a similar thing and I was having major performance problems. Something else you could do to try and speed this up, if the table is being generated via PHP, is put in a `flush()` command every so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jQuery live events](http://api.jquery.com/live/), or [event delegation](http://cherny.com/webdev/70/javascript-event-delegation-and-event-hanlders) and just have a single handler for the table.